# Why is this traits class not working, to test if a class has a certain typedef?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

edit:

OK I figured it out. I was using `false_type` and `true_type` as an argument to `enable_if` when I should have just used `bool`. :x

Further, I have decided that a `is_map_like` class would be better to check if `value_type` is like, `std::pair<const Tkey, Tmapped>`. So, my new traits class looks like this:

```
template<class Tcontainer>
struct is_map_like
{
private:
    template<class TvalueType>
    struct test
    {
        static const bool bvalue = false;
    };
    template<class TkeyType, class TmappedType>
    struct test<std::pair<const TkeyType, TmappedType>>
    {
        static const bool bvalue = true;
    };
public:
    static const bool bvalue = test<typename Tcontainer::value_type>::bvalue;
};
```

---

I want to create a `is_map_like` type traits class that checks for `key_type` and `mapped_type`. I am having a hard time building this. For now I'd like to just check for `key_type`. I have the following so far:

```
template<class T>
struct is_map_like
{
private:
    template<typename C> static std::true_type test(typename C::key_type*);
    template<typename C> static std::false_type test(...);
public:
    typedef decltype(test<T>(0)) value;
};
```

`value` here seems to always return `false_type`. As I understand, SFINAE should allow me to choose the right `test` overload based on whether `C::key_type` is accessible.

Here is how I'm testing: First, a struct that is specialized using `enable_if` on `is_map_like`:

```
// a class that will be specialized only for map-like types
template<class T, class Enable = void>
struct MyStruct
{
    static void fn() { DebugLog(L"T is not a map type"); }
};
template<class T>
struct MyStruct<T, typename std::enable_if<is_map_like<T>::value>::type>
{
    static void fn() { DebugLog(L"T is INDEED a map type"); }
};
```

And here's how I call it at runtime:

```
void test_is_map()
{
    MyStruct<std::vector<int>>::fn();
    MyStruct<std::map<int, int>>::fn();
}
```

The output:

> T is not a map type
>   T is not a map type

What am I doing wrong? Why is the `test(typename C::key_type*)` not used even for the `map`, which indeed has a `key_type`? Or is the problem with my usage of `decltype`?

And bonus: are there any debugging techniques for this? How can I inspect how specializations are chosen, or even get a verification at compile-time about expansion? Maybe there are VS-specific extensions or compile-time debugging tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in the SFINAE structure is a type.

Make it:

```
static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
```

and it will work